# All Office365 folders have disappeared from Thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, imap

My company email is Office365 and I've been using it through Thunderbird for years with no (serious) problems.

I haven't changed any settings or anything, but yesterday I opened Thunderbird on my work computer, and all the folders disappeared except Inbox and Deleted Items.

To see if it was just that computer, I tried on a home computer and the same thing happened.  Both of those are running TB 52.9.1 (to use the AttachmentExtractor addon).  That machine also has Gmail IMAP which has no such problems.

My main home computer is running TB 78.10.2, so I thought maybe it was a version thing, and I backed up all my ImapMail folder and then ran that, and again all folders except Inbox and Deleted Items disappeared.

The only thing in the error console is 6 instances of NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH … nsIXPCComponents_Utils.readUTF8URI

If I click Subscribe... it shows all the folders as unsubscribed, but if I click Subscribe on them, nothing happens.

All the folders still exist on https://outlook.office.com/

If I Subscribe to a folder, and then restart Thunderbird, the folder appears for a second and then disappears.  There are no errors in the error console with timestamps at the moment that it disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to configure your account in other mail clients for testing(such as Windows Mail client)?

Sounds like Thunderbird has compatibility issues syncing with your IMAP account, I found a similar [blog](https://thunderbirdtweaks.blogspot.com/2016/01/outlookcom-office365-imap-subscribed.html) that mentioned disable "Show only subscribed folders" may work for it, please try to uncheck this option for testing if you haven't tried it.

Comment: Outlook can see the folders in view-only mode, but I don't know that it's using IMAP

Comment: What's the meaning of view only mode of Outlook client? For checking the account type in Outlook, as I know, we could click  File>Account settings>Account settings in Outlook for windows.
If that's not IMAP and you need to configure it mannually in Outlook, please follow these steps:Control panel>Mail>Email accounts>New>choose Mannual setup

Comment: The Outlook client isn't paid for, I guess, so it says view only mode.  But it lists all the folders

Comment: I installed eM Client and it imported IMAP settings from Thunderbird, and it shows all the folders, but says "There are no messages to show in this view" for all of them

Comment: Tried Mailbird, it imported my IMAP settings from Thunderbird and shows the folders and the emails in each.  But unlike the others it opened an OAuth "Permissions requested" confirmation thing while importing so I don't know if it's really IMAP. Settings says "Microsoft OAuth 2.0" and server URL `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx` so I don't think it's really IMAP

Comment: It looks like IMAP with OAuth2 is available in the newer Thunderbird but doesn't work on the older one.  Regardless, after setting up OAuth2 on the newer Thunderbird, the disappearing folders still happens.  After subscribe and restart they appear momentarily, but then disappear.

Comment: Activity Manager says, after Subscribe, "The current command did not succeed … SUBSCRIBE failed" Then after restart: "Deleted folder x", etc for each folder I tried to subscribe to. So that looks like the fundamental problem

Comment: The "Show only subscribed folders" workaround does work for me